# How many strings can be formed by reordering the letters ABCDEF so that each string contains the substring EA or the substring CE or both?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinatorics-on-words

How many strings can be formed by reordering the letters ABCDEF so that each string contains
the substring EA or the substring CE or both?

So I thought considering EA as single character there are 5! ways
Considering CE as a single character there are $5!$ ways
considering CEA as a single character there are $4!$ ways which is counted in both EA or CE case so is the total $5!+5!-4!=216$?

Comment: Yes, this is typically the intended approach to a question like this for a student in an introductory course.